# Is a swf of size 350KB really acceptable nowadays?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, size

http://red5.org:5080/demos/publisher.swf

What's the size limit that you can tolerant?

Answer (score 3):

That absolutely depends on what the movie does. If it's just a button even 100kb would be pretty much inacceptable. For a full-featured video player 350kb is probably pretty ok - people watching streaming videos usually have broadband connections anyway.